# OrderedDictionary can't convert value of type '[String : Double]' to specified type 'OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>'

Tags: swift, collections

I'm trying to use `OrderedDictionary` from [Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) and I'm getting the following error when trying to convert a Dictionary to OrderedDictionary.

`Cannot convert value of type '[String : Double]' to specified type 'OrderedDictionary<Key, Value>'`

```
let values: [String: Double]

let sortedDict: OrderedDictionary<String, Double> = values
```

Comment: What would be the order in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler won't let you cast it directly. Instead, pass values to the initializer.

```
let sortedDict: OrderedDictionary<String, Double> = OrderedDictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `uncheckedUniqueKeysWithValues` initialiser:

```
let sortedDict = OrderedDictionary(uncheckedUniqueKeysWithValues: values)
```

It is safe to use this initialiser because `values` is a dictionary, whose keys are always unique. This is "somewhat faster" in optimised builds, according to the documentation comments.

However, unlike the name suggests, the dictionary created this way is not sorted. "Ordered" just means that the entries are guaranteed to be in insertion order. Since the entries in `values` are unordered, `sortedDict` here will get the entries of `value` in a random order, and they will stay in that order in `sortedDict`.

If you want it to be sorted, by keys for example, you need to sort it yourself:

```
let sortedDict = OrderedDictionary(uncheckedUniqueKeysWithValues: 
    values.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
)
```